# How to get TCEFORM in a hook to read altLabels of a dropdown of another extension

Tags: typo3, hook, flexform

I have a hook and try to get a dropdown label text of an other extension. How can i get the flexform typoscript with that values?

Answer (score 0):

Get the TypoScript config with the BackendUtility and look in the TCEFORM of the desired extension:

```
$pageTs = \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility::getPagesTSconfig(1);
$typeLabels = $pageTs['TCEFORM.']['tx_news_domain_model_news.']['type.']['altLabels.'];
```